# Cannot read property 'getReactNativePersistence' of undefined, js engine: hermes

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

First time, long time. I am building a mobile chat app based on Signal, I am using Expo Go and Firebase. I was developing it using the Expo Go mobile app but when i wanted to open it on a local web server i needed to add some logic to the firebase.js file I'm getting the below errors and I can't figure out what to do. I cant find how getReactNativePersistence is called using Firebase documentation.

Has anyone see this issue before?

> ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'getReactNativePersistence' of undefined, js engine: hermes
> ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:\
>
> - Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
> - A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

Here is the firebase.js file:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import {
    firebaseAuth,  
    signInWithEmailAndPassword,
 } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const firebaseConfig = {
   # firebase config
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
let auth;

if (typeof document !== 'undefined') {
    // Web environment
    auth = firebaseAuth.getAuth(app);
    firebaseAuth.setPersistence(auth, firebaseAuth.browserSessionPersistence);
} else {
    // React Native environment
    const reactNativePersistence = firebaseAuth.getReactNativePersistence;
    auth = firebaseAuth.initializeAuth(app, {
      persistence: reactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage)
    });
}

const db = getFirestore(app);

// Exporting the necessary Firebase services and functions
export { db, auth, signInWithEmailAndPassword };
```

I used chatgpt to help me troubleshoot it, yes it tried the robot, and using it fixed the issue but it was more of a warning. but now i'm not sure what is going. the stopping the app from running.

This was the file prior to making the changes.

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/auth";

// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
  # firebase set up
};

let app;
if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
  app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
} else {
  app = firebase.app();
}

const db = app.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();

export { db, auth };
```